# Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, traefik

I intend to use version v2.0 of Traefik and have therefore tested something first. If I want to use the Swarm Mode, I always get the following log entries:

```
time="2019-09-22T21:30:28Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2377. Is the docker daemon running?, retrying in 507.606314ms" providerName=docker
time="2019-09-23T05:58:39Z" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2377. Is the docker daemon running?" providerName=docker
```

My docker.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik
```

My traefik.toml file:

```
[providers]
    [providers.docker]
        endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2377"
        swarmMode = true
        watch = true

[api]
    insecure = true

[log]
    level = "DEBUG"
```

Ports:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEND

dockerd    501   root   24u  IPv6  858243      0t0  TCP *:2377 (LISTEN)
dockerd    501   root   30u  IPv6  858280      0t0  TCP *:7946 (LISTEN)
dockerd    501   root   40u  IPv6 1024853      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
dockerd    501   root   58u  IPv6 1024882      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
sshd       510   root    3u  IPv4   13105      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       510   root    4u  IPv6   13115      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
glusterd   514   root   10u  IPv4   13127      0t0  TCP *:24007 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Do not mix `traefik.toml`, environment vars and command line, it is not supported. `endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2377"` will only work if your docker swarm manager listens to port `2377` on `127.0.0.1`. I suggest you comment this line out. Finally, whoami does not listen on `8080`

Comment: I have deleted the command line vars, no positive result.

Comment: You probably want to do all the changes, I suggested.

Comment: The problem is not whoami, I can't reach the traefik dashboard.

Comment: I hear you. You need to do changes for _all_ those things I suggested in the first comment to make progress.

Comment: Okay. Now I've changed everything you suggested, but it's the same error. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199825/discussion-between-andrew-savinykh-and-beta-logics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what ressolved it for me was to move the docker volumes containing the docker unix socket and the TLS certs to the corresponding docker-compose section.

My goal is to have a proxy to manager a Bitbucket app. Check my sample below

```
services:

proxy-traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: proxy_traefik
    restart: always
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Traefik dashboard
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command:
      ## CLI commands to configure Traefik and tell it how to work!
      ## API Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/operations/api/, endpoints - https://docs.traefik.io/operations/api/#endpoints
      - --api.insecure=true # <== Enabling insecure api, NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRODUCTION
      - --api.dashboard=true # <== Enabling the dashboard to view services, middlewares, routers, etc
      - --api.debug=true # <== Enabling additional endpoints for debugging and profiling
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      ## Provider Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/#provider-configuration
      - --providers.docker=true # <== Enabling docker as the provider for traefik
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false # only expose enabled containers
      ## Entrypoints Settings - https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#configuration
      - --entrypoints.app.address=:80 # <== Defining an entrypoint for port :80 named web
      - --entrypoints.app-secured.address=:443 # <== Defining an entrypoint for https on port :443 named app-secured
    labels:
      ## Labels define the behavior and rules of the traefik proxy for this container ####
      - "traefik.enable=true" # <== Enable traefik on itself to view dashboard and assign subdomain to view it
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`monitor.${BITBUCKET_DOMAIN}`)" # <== Setting the domain for the dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal" # <== Enabling the api to be a service to access
      - "com.navico.rnd.app=bitbucket_proxy"
      - "com.navico.rnd.env=prod"
      - "com.navico.rnd.name_file=traefik"
    volumes:
      # - /home/ubuntu/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml # not using toml anymore
      - ./tls_certs:/navicotls # <== Volume for certs (TLS)
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```